# Angular 4 - Not getting current element

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using `ngFor` to render data, now I want to show div on click of edit icon but I am not able to get current element.

```
<tr *ngFor="let serviceDetail of serviceDetailsList; let i = index">
   <td>{{serviceDetail.serviceName}}</td> 
    <td>{{serviceDetail.serviceVersion}}</td>
    <td>{{serviceDetail.isLatest}}</td>
    <td>
        <div class="showUrl" >
          <span class="icon-edit" id="i" #editIc (click)="edit()" ></span>
        </div>

        <div class="editUrl" id="show" style="display: none">
          <input type="text" name="" class="editUrl" #myInputText>
          <a style="margin: 0 10px;" (click)="sendToServer('save')">Save</a>

          <a class="urlClass" (click)="sendToServer()">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>


 @ViewChild('editIc') editIc:ElementRef;
  edit(){
    let thisPElem = this.editIc.nativeElement.parentElement;
    let thisPSibling = thisPElem.nextElementSibling;
    thisPElem.style.display = 'none';
    thisPSibling.style.display = 'block';

    console.log(thisPElem);

  }
```

Comment: any error while compiling or on console?

Comment: No error in compilation or in console. getting first element every time, if clicked on another.

Comment: add the full code

Comment: Is there a good reason why you are trying to do direct DOM manipulation instead of modifying state and letting Angular update the DOM for you?

Comment: @GregL that's a good point. instead of hide an show, an ngIf will do the job more perfectly

Comment: I just want to show element on click of edit for currant row. If I used event then it's show/hide all elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass the $event object into the function. Inside the $event object, you can find the element by accessing the property.

```
<tr *ngFor="let serviceDetail of serviceDetailsList; let i = index">
   <td>{{serviceDetail.serviceName}}</td> 
    <td>{{serviceDetail.serviceVersion}}</td>
    <td>{{serviceDetail.isLatest}}</td>
    <td>
        <div class="showUrl" >
          <span class="icon-edit" id="i" #editIc (click)="edit($event)" ></span>
        </div>

        <div class="editUrl" id="show" style="display: none">
          <input type="text" name="" class="editUrl" #myInputText>
          <a style="margin: 0 10px;" (click)="sendToServer('save')">Save</a>

          <a class="urlClass" (click)="sendToServer()">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>

// function in your class
edit($event){
    let thisPElem = $event.target;
    let thisPSibling = thisPElem.nextSibling;
    thisPElem.style.display = 'none';
    thisPSibling.style.display = 'block';

    console.log(thisPElem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `*ngIf`, which will show/hide the divs. Keep the track of the state with a property (e.g. `edit` bellow). It will keep the row index value. Set it bak to -1 to go back.

HTML:

```
<div class="showUrl" *ngIf="edit !== i">
  <span class="icon-edit" id="i" #editIc (click)="edit=i" ></span>
</div>

<div class="editUrl" *ngIf="edit === i" id="show">
  <input type="text" name="" class="editUrl" #myInputText>
  <a style="margin: 0 10px;" (click)="sendToServer('save');edit = -1">Save</a>

  <a class="urlClass" (click)="sendToServer();edit = -1">Cancel</a>
</div>
```

**TyepScript**:

```
edit = -1;
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b71vrt?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score -1):

you can pass argument in edit function

```
<span class="icon-edit" id="i" #editIc (click)="edit(i)" ></span>
//or
<span class="icon-edit" id="i" #editIc (click)="edit(serviceDetail )" ></span>
```